# Moving average for value present in two dataframe columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm stuck with the following problem since last night and I haven't found any solution anywhere.

Given the dataframe `df`:

```
  team1 team2 score1 score2
0     A     B      1      0
1     C     A      3      2
2     B     A      2      3
3     A     C      2      1
```

I would like to pass a function that calculates **moving average** for the `team1` BUT take into account both `team1` and `team2` columns.

The output for moving average of 2 would be:

```
  team1 team2 score1 score2 mov_avg_a
0     A     B      1      2         1   # for A
1     C     A      3      2       1.5   # for C
2     B     A      2      3       2.5   # for B
3     A     C      2      1       2.5   # for A
```

My idea is to call `.apply()` with custom function that would:

Step 1. Blend `team1` and `team2` columns into a temporary column `tempA` with `score1` and `score2` values are returned if A (for example) is present, like so:

```
  team1 team2 score1 score2 tempA
0     A     B      1      0     1
1     C     A      3      2     2
2     B     A      2      3     3
3     A     C      2      1     2
```

Step 2. Apply `rolling(2)` to the `tempA` to get the desired output as seen above.

I have tried creating this process and failed spectacularly.

I am aware that using `apply()` in the case of large dataframe will be computationally expensive but I cannot think of a 'one line' solution here.

Thank you in advance for your insights.

Dataframe for tests:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'team1': ['A', 'C', 'B', 'A'],
        'team2': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'C'],
        'score1': [1, 3, 2, 2],
        'score2': [0, 2, 3, 1]
    }
    )
```

EDIT:

Upon some further thoughts I think the best solution is to create two separate datasets for team1 and team2 each, perform calculations on them and merge them back if needed.

Comment: I must confess I am confused. I would expect `df['tempA'].rolling(2).mean()` to yield `[NaN, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5]` not `[1, 3, 2, 2]`

Comment: Ray, well spotted, thanks. Although for first value with `min_periods=1` it would yield 1.

Answer (score 1):

Given the clarification in comments I'll suggest this...

```py
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
  team1 team2  score1  score2
0     A     B       1       0
1     C     A       3       2
2     B     A       2       3
3     A     C       2       1

In [3]: # restructure data frame
   ...: df_team_scores = pd.wide_to_long(df.assign(game_index=df.index),
   ...:         ['team', 'score'],
   ...:         i='game_index',
   ...:         j='column_suffix')
   ...: df_team_scores
Out[3]:
                         team  score
game_index column_suffix
0          1                A      1
1          1                C      3
2          1                B      2
3          1                A      2
0          2                B      0
1          2                A      2
2          2                A      3
3          2                C      1

In [4]: # restore proper of scores (in order of game_index)
   ...: # order by team first to make table easier to understand
   ...: df_team_scores = df_team_scores.reset_index().sort_values(['team', 'game_index'])
   ...: df_team_scores
Out[4]:
   game_index  column_suffix team  score
0           0              1    A      1
5           1              2    A      2
6           2              2    A      3
3           3              1    A      2
4           0              2    B      0
2           2              1    B      2
1           1              1    C      3
7           3              2    C      1

In [5]: # Compute the rolling score
   ...: s_rolling_score = df_team_scores.groupby(by='team')['score'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean()
   ...: s_rolling_score
Out[5]:
team
A     0    1.0
      5    1.5
      6    2.5
      3    2.5
B     4    0.0
      2    1.0
C     1    3.0
      7    2.0
Name: score, dtype: float64

In [6]: # Force indices to be compatible and merge back to team_scores data frame
   ...: df_team_scores['rolling_score'] = s_rolling_score.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
   ...: df_team_scores
Out[6]:
   game_index  column_suffix team  score  rolling_score
0           0              1    A      1            1.0
5           1              2    A      2            1.5
6           2              2    A      3            2.5
3           3              1    A      2            2.5
4           0              2    B      0            0.0
2           2              1    B      2            1.0
1           1              1    C      3            3.0
7           3              2    C      1            2.0
```

Not quite a one-liner but does not rely on custom functions. If you need to merge this back into the original data frame, I'll leave it to someone else to figure it out.